# Conditional rolling sum based on another column

Tags: r

I would like to compute the conditional rolling sum of a column, but based on the values of another column.

I have a table like this:

```
    
    data_frame <- data.frame( category1 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B"), 
                              category2 = c("B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A"),
                                 value = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 5, 3, 4, 2),
                              desired_output = c(0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 11))
  
  
    data_frame2 <- data_frame %>% 
      group_by(category1) %>% 
      mutate(cumsum = cumsum(value))
```

```
category1   category2   value   cumsum  desired_output
A   B   1   1   0
A   B   2   3   0
A   B   1   4   0
B   A   2   2   4
B   A   1   3   4
B   A   5   8   4
A   B   3   7   8
A   B   4   11  8
B   A   2   10  11
```

I am able to compute the rolling sum of the value based on category1 or category2 using cumsum, but I would like a column which calculates a rolling sum of the value column when category1 equals the current value of category2. For example, in the last row of the above example it sums the value of all the above rows when category1 == A, as the current value of category2 is A.

I have tried various hacky ifelse/lag/fill solutions but nothing gets close to what I need. I have also tried adding a conditional into the ave function, as below, but not sure what the syntax should be...

```
data_frame2$desired_output <- ave(data_frame2$value, data_frame2$category1 = data_frame2$category2,  FUN=cumsum)
```

Thanks in advance - first question so apologies about anything I missed/got wrong!

Comment: Use `==` instead of “=“. The latter is NOT a logical operation in R.

Comment: In the example `data_frame2$category1 == data_frame2$category2` is always `FALSE`

Comment: Correct - it is always FALSE in that example. I'm not sure if there is a way to construct the conditional to make it work.